# NSFileManager.attributesOfItemAtPath vs USURL.getResourceValue for file size and modification date

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsfilemanager

I need to get the size and last modification date of several files stored locally in iOS (specifically the temp directory). The file is referenced by a `NSURL`:

```
let fileURL: NSURL = ...
```

I've found two way of doing this:

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(fileURL.path!)[NSFileSize]
```

and

```
var size: AnyObject?
fileURL.getResourceValue(&size, forKey: "NSURLFileSizeKey")
```

What's the difference between the two? Is one more performant than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One takes a path, one takes a file URL. Depending on how you start, it may be better to use the path or the URL.

There are various `NSFileManager` methods that let you enumerate file URLs and preload specific file attributes. If you are using one of those APIs, then using `getResourceValue` on the `NSURL` will be more efficient since the data is already in place.

`NSURL getResourceValue` is likely a tiny bit more efficient because `NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath` likely (maybe?) preloads all of its file attributes which would be less efficient than getting individual attributes. But that's an implementation detail.

In the end, this is premature optimization. Use which ever one is easier to write and maintain. Don't worry about performance unless you have a performance issue that needs to be dealt with.

Comment: In my case I'm getting the file URLs from `NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(tempDir, includingPropertiesForKeys: [String](), options: [])`, where tempDir is `NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)`, so yes, it's starting off from NSFileManager

Comment: Then update the `includingPropertiesForKeys` parameter value to include the actual file attributes you wish to access using `getResourceValue`. This will be more efficient than using `attributesOfItemAtPath` since you already have an `NSURL` and can preload the needed attributes.